# Heroku and jetty error

Tags: heroku, jetty, manifest

The app (basic java server with jetty and maven) doesn't run when i do "heroku local"

[first try: (error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRGZf.png)

pom.xml: [Full pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/eWVwvRrA)

```
<plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>

      <configuration>
        <additionalProperties>
            <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
            <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
            <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
            <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
          </additionalProperties>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

[second try: (error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHNeB.png)

pom.xml change: [Full pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/CbaPf3a8)

```
<plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>

      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>target/classes/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.example.WS_Server</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <additionalProperties>
            <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
            <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
            <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
            <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
          </additionalProperties>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Sorry for posting the full xml on pastebin but i'm not able to integrate it with the post itself, it gets al breaked and i receive error not letting me to create the post, i don't understand how it works.

Please help cuz i'm getting creazy with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that tried to help!
I finally got this working!!! OMG i'm so happy!!!
This battle was really hard!!!
I've been trying to make this work for weeks!

So to start the first problem was that i had the build pack assigned to JVM insted of JAVA, after solving that the app started to build successfully waiting for a connection, and that was the second problem, i've descovered that we cant set a PORT becouse heroku takes care of that so we have to get the variable were that por is saved, so after that i started the client, the connection happened and the server and client transmit data to each other successfully!

I'll try to make a video tutorial on how to make this and post it here.